# SQL Best way to return data from one table along with mapped data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have the following problem.

I have a **table** `Entries` that contains 2 columns:

- `EntryID` - unique identifier
- `Name` - some name

I have another `EntriesMapping` **table** (**many to many** mapping table) that contains 2 columns :

- `EntryID` that refers to the `EntryID` of the `Entries` table
- `PartID` that refers to a `PartID` in a seprate `Parts` table.

I need to write a **SP** that will return **all data** from `Entries` table, but for each row in the `Entries` table I want to provide a **list of all** `PartID`'s that are registered in the `EntriesMapping` table.

My question is how do I best approach the deisgn of the solution to this, given that the results of the **SP** would regularly be processed by an app so performance is quite important.

**1.**
Do I write a SP that will select **multiple rows per entry** - where if there are more than one `PartID`'s registered for a given entry - I will return multiple rows each having the same `EntryID` and `Name` but different `PartID`'s

**OR**

**2.**
Do I write a SP that will select **1 row per entry** in the `Entries` table, and have a field that is a **string/xml/json** that contains all the different `PartID`'s.

**OR**

**3. There is some other solution that I  am not thinking of?**

**Solution 1** seems to me to be the better way to go, but I will be passing lots of repeating data.

**Solution 2** wont pass extra data, but the **string/json/xml** would need to be processed additionally, resuling in larger cpu time per item.

PS: I feel like this is quite a common problem to solve, but I was unable to find any resource that can provide common solutions or some pros/cons to different approaches.

Comment: (1) Stored procedures do not "return" anything, other than an integer status value.  (2) Why wouldn't you use a view, scalar function, or table-valued function?  (3) Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of coming from a more OOP langugae background. 
The stored procedure will do a select and provide the results of the select to the client app that is calling it. I'm not worried about wheter I need to have a SP/View/func ... but more like - how do I deisgn it

Comment: @Kobek Please, edit your question to add sample data and expected results  with what did you try to solve your issue, all as _formatted text_ not images please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.EntryId, e.Name, em.PartId
FROM Entries e
JOIN EntriesMapping em ON e.EntryId = em.EntryId
```

This will return what you want, no need for stored procedure for that.

Comment: I really didn't mean to put any emphasis on the SP. 
Even without one.. my question is, should I do what you are suggesting and end up with multiple rows per Entry. Or  write a more complex query, that will put all the entry mappings in a new JSON/XML/VARCHAR field. Which of these would be a better design

Comment: @Kobek It's totally up to you what and what you want to get :) but this select will be better in terms of performance :)

Comment: @Kobek it's upto you, if you don't tell us how you are using this data we won't be able to provide any advice